# Javascript function on vbulletin forum successfully changing innerhtml for one tag but not the other

Tags: javascript, html

On a small vbulletin forum i run I wanted to change all my users' names to the same thing, which I was able to do successfully with this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    window.onload = function triedSoHard() {
        // grab all of the username elements
        var userNames = document.getElementsByClassName('bigusername');

        // iterate and apply slit wrists to everyone
        for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
            var internal = userNames[i].getElementsByTagName('span');
            // should be only one span, so just go with the first one
            internal[0].innerHTML = "it doesn't even matter"; 
        }
    }   
</script>
```

I attempted to add a second loop to the script to edit users' titles, as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function triedSoHard() {
        // grab all of the username elements
        var userNames = document.getElementsByClassName('bigusername');

        // iterate and apply slit wrists to everyone
        for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
            var internal = userNames[i].getElementsByTagName('span');
            // should be only one span, so just go with the first one
            internal[0].innerHTML = "it doesn't even matter"; 
        }

        // grab all of the title elements
        var userTitles = document.getElementsByClassName('smallfont');

        // iterate and apply slit wrists to everyone
        for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
            userTitles[i].innerHTML = "spacewhale"; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

but this didn't work.

The forum name is www.sexaypartay.com (note: NOT ACTUALLY A SEX FORUM IN ANY WAY)

The username html is

```
<a class="bigusername" href="member.php?u=2"><span class="sexayfifths">Fifthfiend</span></a>
```

and the user title html is

```
<div class="smallfont">nine suns nipple clamp</div>
```

(I SWEAR TO GOD, NOT ACTUALLY A SEX FORUM)